Sequential (1D) data: how to detect patterns
I have some input data that is a sequence (it's a sensor data over time). I want to identify some recurring patterns.
For example, imagine that the data is the temperature measured by a sensor over time. Regularly, the temperature drops for a little while before climbing back to normal. However, the length, shape and magnitude of this drop has some variation (this represents someone opening the door of the room).
I am able to label the data (the drop is quite recognizable), and if it helps, we can consider that two patterns can't overlap (there is only one door, so you can't make the temperature drop twice at the same time)
Still, I have no idea how I could analyze the sequence to output all the occurences of the pattern.
It looks like a 1-D version of image detection (think of the boxes that YOLO outputs, except 1-D).
What I am looking for : the name of this problem so I can read the literature and/or some algorithm to solve the problem.
Important note : I am allowed to perform inference long after the data is collected (i.e: I am not restricted to past data, I have access to the entire sequence)

[tag:hidden-markov-model]? Or even simpler, just check when the first differences exceeds some value.

Of course, machine learning comes tomind (as you say you can label the data, so you can train the model). Another option is mathematical morphology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology It was developed to exactly detect/analyze objects based on their "shape"; it works in 1D (signal processing), 2D (images) and higher order spatioal structures.
